# Lots of Unknown Process, Which one can be disabled? and How?

Tags: centos

Weird Process, Which one can be disabled? and How?

Hi, Im just upgrade from VPS to dedicated server.
In VPS, the RAM usage is about 50MB.

But in this new dedicated server, the RAM usage is more than 400MB

I dont know what process needs too much RAM,

and when looking at `top`, there's so many unknown process

`top - 03:54:51 up 15:35,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

Tasks: 100 total,   1 running,  99 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie

Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Mem:   2065588k total,   440844k used,  1624744k free,    81392k buffers

Swap:  7823644k total,        0k used,  7823644k free,   294504k cached



  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                

 3648 root      15   0  2204 1008  800 R  0.9  0.0   0:00.08 top                                    

    1 root      15   0  2072  580  500 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.88 init                                   

    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 migration/0                            

    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                            

    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                             

    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/1                            

    6 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                            

    7 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                             

    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/2                            

    9 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2                            

   10 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2                             

   11 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/3                            

   12 root      39  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3                            

   13 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/3                             

   14 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/0                               

   15 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/1                               

   16 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/2                               

   17 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/3                               

   18 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khelper                                

   19 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthread                                

   25 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/0                              

   26 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/1    


   27 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/2    


   28 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/3    


   29 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid       


  120 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/0     


  121 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/1     


  122 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/2`

So,
Which one can be disabled? and How?

Thanks in advance

(The server running CentOS 5.3)

Answer (score 4):

They can't, or at least they shouldn't. All of them apart from top and init (from your listing) are kernel processes, and init is the parent process (either directly or indirectly) of everything running on your linux box. If you also observe the VIRT/RES columns of your top output, most of the processes you list have 0 in these columns, they don't contribute towards your memory usage in any traditional way.

Your "actual" memory usage is closer to 64Mb ( used - buffers - cached ). Buffers/cache are used by the linux kernel to i.e. cache the filesystem. Unused ram is wasted ram, hence the kernel uses it for buffers/cache, the ram will be made available if an application requests it.

See also [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/13746/linux-eats-all-memory-seems-like-it-is-not-for-specific-application), which posts some links to understanding linux memory management/usage.

Answer (score 2):

All the processes you list (typically those ending with /1 and /2) are all kernel threads they are linked with functionality in the kernel and most of them you can't or you don't really want to disabled. ksoftirqd is processing software interrupts (/0 means running on the first cpu, /0 running on the 2nd cpu. ...), watchdog/0 takes care of the watchdog chip, and so forth ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not an expert but I was under the impression that free memory is used to pre-cache files from the HDD to improve system performance.

I'm sure someone on here can give you a better answer though...