# All memory consumed by MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linux eats all memory, seems like it is not for specific application](https://serverfault.com/questions/13746/linux-eats-all-memory-seems-like-it-is-not-for-specific-application)

TOP shows that almost all the memory is consued on a dedicated MySQL box.
I stopped mysql and checked the top and there is no difference. There is no other process running that would consume that kind of memory.
How do I release the locked memory?

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld status
mysqld dead but subsys locked

# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         35007      34913         94          0        186      33045
-/+ buffers/cache:       1681      33326
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Do I need to restart the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the third line (`-/+ buffers/cache`) which shows you memory used by the operating system for filesystem buffers and caches, but that can immediately be made available for use by any process which needs it. You do not have a memory shortage.

Comment: When I start mysql, the queries are extremely slow. How do I know if it is an OS issue or MySQL ?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question, with more details of your MySql configuration and OS, and whether it is all queries (even trivial ones) that are slow or just some (in which case look at the slow query log). You might also investigate "mysqld dead but subsys locked" in your OP.

Comment: Actually, now you know how to read its output, you should run the free command while MySql is running.