# Where did my memory go? linux box

Tags: linux, memory

I just got a linux box and i installed apache, mono and i'm about to install mysql.

I checked the memory with free -mt and got this.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           492        470         22          0         31        343
```

This means i have 492mb in total and i am using 470!?! how can i be using 470! i should only be running apache2. How do i figure out where my ram is going.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Red Hat Linux report less free memory on the system than is actually available?](http://serverfault.com/questions/9442/why-does-red-hat-linux-report-less-free-memory-on-the-system-than-is-actually-ava)

Comment: I am sure its NOT reporting memory falsely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-/+ buffers/cache` displays the actual memory available on the `free` column.  Linux uses unused memory for caching disk I/O.

Comment: So i am using 95mb and have 397 cached?
-/+ buffers/cache:         95        397

Comment: 397 would be the free amount if I'm reading what you're attempting to say correctly.  See also: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use [top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) and/or [vmstat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?vmstat) for further analysis of memory and memory usage in Linux.

Comment: "sar" is another good command too.

Comment: dstat FTW.  'dstat -af' has never failed to give me a good idea of what is going on in the system.  That is, if my terminal is wide enough.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
top -d 0.5
```

and if you want post the output