# apache2/php workaround

Tags: apache-2.2

Since i faced issues with apache2 processes eating all my memory within short time, i found a workaround like this cronjob:

`0,15,30,45 * * * * [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete`

Before my RAM load is 2GB and after cronjob ran, it's 500MB load => 1.5GB free.

The cronjob is set to run on 0,15,30,45 every hour. Isn't there a proper solution which keeps the apache2 in check to avoid running out of memory within any 15min?

http://nopaste.info/a4de552b95.html

Comment: You seem to have some confusion between RAM and storage.  Deleting files won't free up RAM unless they are in a ramdisk.  Something else changed your RAM usage.  What does `top` show for Apache's RAM usage?

Comment: That command deletes the old session files.  That has nothing to do with RAM.

Comment: Paste your ps aux pls

Comment: @Zoredache: I can't imagine that only the session files take 1,5GB of RAM.

Comment: @Andrew Smith: the memory usage + free output: http://nopaste.info/a4de552b95.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues here; it certainly doesn't look like you're running out of memory, with only 608MB used. I suspect you need to read [Linux Ate My RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

See also [this question and answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/9442/why-does-red-hat-linux-report-less-free-memory-on-the-system-than-is-actually-av).