# On Unix/Linux OS machines are showing less memory

Tags: linux, unix, memory

Why on Unix/Linux OS machines are showing less memory (RAM) than it is? Let say i have Ubuntu machine whose have 1024 MB ram, when i open "System Monitor" "Resources" tab it shows 1001.2 MB. How i can get all RAM from Unix/Linux machines?

link doesn't help -[Why does Red Hat Linux report less free memory on the system than is actually available?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9442/why-does-red-hat-linux-report-less-free-memory-on-the-system-than-is-actually-av)

Comment: Minimalism can be nice, but not when asking questions.

Comment: And very, very likely to go in this direction: http://serverfault.com/questions/9442/why-does-red-hat-linux-report-less-free-memory-on-the-system-than-is-actually-av

Comment: Please provide more information then flag to have your question reopened, providing the link above doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @krapstuke: Doesn't the answer from James help?

Comment: @SvenW no. i need proper solution to get this via terminal at least.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Before you continue, please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), as well as [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided a very vague sentence but i'll do my best. You likely have an integrated graphics card. A portion of the ram will be taken for video memory. You should be able to control how much is taken in bios.

Comment: i need terminal command, not BIOS. I'm testing it on virtual machines

Comment: @krapstuke: Why don't you give us the whole picture in the question? This kind of information is relevant, now we would like to know which virt tool you are using. In most (all?) products you can control how much video RAM the machines have available somewhere in the virtual machine settings. This will be taken from the total memory you gave the machine.

Comment: @SvenW tool doesn't matter. Video memory is separated from ram. Chill out. Do you know the way to get Total ram in terminal?

Comment: @krapstuke Having seen your updated question please read this explanation on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)